# Geom_ribbon() just turns the graph blank

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I got a data frame `weekly.mean.values` with the following structure:

```
week:mean:ci.lower:ci.upper
```

Where week is a factor; mean, ci.lower and ci.upper are numeric. For each week, there is only one mean, and one ci.lower or ci.upper.

I was trying to plot a shaded area inside of the 95% confidence interval around the mean, with the following code:

```
ggplot(weekly.mean.values,aes(x=week,y=mean)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=ci.lower,ymax=ci.upper))
```

The plot, however, came out blank (that is only with x-axis and y-axis present, but no lines, or points, let alone shaded areas).

If I removed the geom_ribbon part, I did get a line. I know that this should be a very simple task but I don't know why I couldn't get geom_ribbon to plot what I wanted. Any hint would be truly appreciated.

Comment: You should provide a small [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/324364) example that illustrates this behavior. It's difficult for us to magically know what's happening on your computer.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this thread is super old, but google still find it.

The answer is that you need to set the `ymin` and `ymax` to use a part of the data you are using on the `y-axis`. It you set them to scalar values then the ribbon covers the entire plot from top to bottom.

You can use

```
ymin=0 
ymax=mean
```

to go from 0 to your `y-point` or even

```
ymin=mean-1
ymax=mean+1
```

to have the ribbon cover a strip encompassing your actual data.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but the ribbon will be plotted filled with `grey20` by default. You are plotting this layer **on top** of the data so no wonder it obscures it. Also, it is also possible that the limits for the plot axes derived from the data provided to the initial `ggplot()` call will not be sufficient to contain the confidence interval ribbon. In that case, I would not be surprised to see a grey/blank plot.

To see if this is the problem, try altering your `geom_ribbon()` line to:

```
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=ci.lower,ymax=ci.upper), alpha = 0.5)
```

which will plot the ribbon with transparency whic should show the data underneath if the problem is what I think it is.

If so, set the x and y limits to the range of the data +/- the confidence interval you wish to plot and swap the order of the layers (i.e. draw the line on top of the ribbon), and use transparency in the ribbon to show the grid through it.

Answer (score 1):

From [ggplot's docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_ribbon.html) for `geom_ribbon` (2.1.0):

> For each continuous x value, `geom_interval` displays a y interval. `geom_area` is a special case of `geom_ribbon`, where the minimum of the range is fixed to 0.

In this case, x values cannot be factors for `geom_ribbon`. One solution would be to convert `week` from a factor to a numeric. e.g.

```
ggplot(weekly.mean.values,aes(x=as.numeric(week),y=mean)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=ci.lower,ymax=ci.upper))
```

`geom_line` should handle the switch from factor to numeric without incident, although the X axis scale may display differently.